# Почему не импортируется Switch из 'react-router-dom'?

Tags: react-router-dom

Почему не импортируется Switch из react-router-dom ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Делаю проект на React и надо импортировать <Switch> из 'react-router-dom' , но он не импортируется . Хотя <Route> и <Router> импортировались

Answer (score 0):

Вы какую версию react-router используете? если версия 6, то там нет Switch. Его заменили на Routes.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]